# Sonar is saying to use an private constructor instead of an implicit public constructor but the constructor is used in tests

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a controller class and sonar is saying i should add a private constructor that throws an error but the class is used in a test class so doing this would cause the tests to fail.
So should I add a public constructor to the class just so sonar doesn't pick it up?

Comment: "*So should I add a public constructor*" Isn't it already public ?

Comment: you could always go for package private, or protected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always customize Sonar so that it won't show such unuseful errors. Many of the checks may be valid only in specific cases. You can either disable this config for your whole project or put `// NOSONAR` at the end of the line so that Sonar ignores that. Also you can ask Sonar to ignore a file by putting the following annotation on top of your class:

```
@java.lang.SuppressWarnings("squid:S00112")
```

in which the value after `squid:` is the rule code corresponding to the rule that you're talking about.

Comment: I added it to the top of the class and it said "Annotations are not allowed here"